# Italicize a word every time it appears on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a web page for the Podunk company. But every time Podunk appears on the page (no matter where it is) it needs to be shown as *Podunk!*

Note that this is ANYWHERE on the page so it could be in header tags, list tags, in multiple nested DIVs, etc.

What is the best way to go about this? I'm thinking that jQuery is the better solution (as opposed to CSS) but I don't know how to go about it? Can someone please provide a code snippet for this kind of replacement on an entire page element.

Comment: Actually, if you have control over the code, wrapping it in spans styled with italic text-decoration in CSS would be a lot better IMO.

Comment: Look for a word highlighting plugin, there are many out there that will do this for you. It isn't a very simple task to take on on your own if you must do it with javascript.

Comment: What @adeneo said. Use a global find-and-replace in your HTML editor, wrap them in `<span class="podunk">...</span>` and add an `!important` CSS style. If you try to do this automatically in jQuery it will eventually screw something up.

Comment: Are you willing to use a third party library like jQuery?

Comment: However, if you did wish to attempt to roll your own, start by getting a collection of all text nodes on the page, then iterate through them looking for that word. When you find it, split the text node in half removing the word and then place a <em /> in-between them that contains the word.

Comment: !important is a blunt tool. Better to use a more-specific CSS selector.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I need a dynamic solution since these pages are actually served up by joomla and need to find all instances on dynamic pages

Comment: @JimBeam You won't get one that's dynamic, you'll need to run whatever method you decide on when it's needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My original answer was incorrect (as pointed out in the comment :) ) I have edited this answer to include the correct solution.

```
var rgx = /Podunk/g;
$("body *")
    .contents()
    .filter(function() {
        if (this.nodeType !== 3){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    })
    .each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var txt = $this.text();
        if (rgx.test(txt)){
            $this.replaceWith("<span>" + txt.replace(rgx,"<span class='podunk'>Podunk</span>") + "</span>");
        };
    });​
```

This has the downside that any element that has only Podunk in it gets and additional span element. ie, if you have

```
<a>Podunk</a>
```

you end up with

```
<a><span><span class="podunk">Podunk</span></span>.
```

I think with a little consideration this could be overcome.

Comment: This is great, however, it replaces within attributes too which can have odd side effects. Hover over the link in this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/j7tHT/ It will also destroy any event handlers or data that is stored on the elements that are being replaced in this way.

Comment: @Kevin This is true but the word is so unique (their trademark) that it might not make a difference in the long run

Answer (score 1):

If it needs to appear in italics, the absolute surest way is to use `<i>Podunk</i>` and to make the best effort to ensure that the font family used has an italic typeface.

It is a misguided aim anyway, so you should not worry about colleagues saying that the `i` markup is not “semantic”. But you might consider using `<i class=company>Podunk</i>`, just to make it easier to drop such use of italic without dropping sensible uses of italic, should the client come to their senses.